# Android 13: system language mix with english

Tags: languages

My friend just bought a new phone, Samsung S23.

He wanted to have the system language set to his mother language (Hungarian), but the phone didn't offer this language during initial setup so he selected English.

After the setup completed (again this was a brand new phone, he opened the box), he installed Hungarian in Settings/General management/Language.

Now he has mixed language: menus on Android in general are in Hungarian, but for example, the settings application is still in English.

Can I help him to do something to have a fluid 100% Hungarian menu everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You just installed the language. You have to change the app languages too

- On your Android phone, open your Settings app.
- Tap System and then
- Languages & input and then App languages.
- Select the app you want to change.
- Choose a language.

(Correct me if im wrong. I havent looked it up. Its what i remember what i did the last time i did it)

**EDIT:**
Settings > System > Languages you should see English and Hungarian here numbered as

1. English
2. Hungarian

Drag the Hungarian to 1. position pressing and holding the two small dashes (like = sign) beside it. Language should change right away.

Comment: His "Settings" app stayed English, and it's not listed in *App languages*.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please check

Comment: He has Hungarian at first place. Not working, "Settings" app is still in English. He also tried to entirely remove "English" which also not making settings menu items Hungarian.

Comment: @Daniel Hmm.. that's odd. Is it only the settings app which is in english or are there more apps? Can you confirm what's in `Settings > System > Language & Input > App Language > Settings app`

Comment: "Settings app" is not listed nor selectable in "App Language". :( And yes only Settings app is in English.

Comment: That's very starnge, it shouldn't behave like that. Try resetting and selecting the language right off from the set up screen. (Also I dont have a samsung but do you see any option in `App Language` as show system apps?)

Comment: AND before that could you add another random language(other than eng and hun) at 2. and tell if the settings language changes? It might be possible that settings app doesn't support Hungarian, in that case 2nd language is used. So just to make sure. The order in Languages should look something like `1. Hungarian  2. Chinese  3. English`